# AD user locked out of Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Our ubuntu server is joined to our Windows domain and a group of users are allowed to SSH into the server. One of the admins has somehow locked his account and he cannot SSH into the server anymore. The user account does not show as locked on the AD server. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: had a similar issue, and what was still locking the account was pam rules on the server itself.